# Values for touch locations fall out of view's bounds

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, touch

I am trying to record the locations of the touches. Below is my code. As far as I understand, a touch at the very far upper left corner would give me a location of (0,0), and the very far lower right corner would be (768, 1024) supposing I'm holding the iPad in portrait. However, I'm getting values like (-6, -18) for the upper left corner and (761,1003) for the lower right. It looks like the coordinates are shifted somehow. A trace of self.bounds does give me {{0,0}, {768, 1024}}. Can someone explain this to me? I would like to get x and y value that are between the bounds {{0,0}, {768, 1024}}. Thank you very much in advance.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
     CGRect bounds = [self bounds]; 
     NSLog(@"frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(bounds)); // this value was traced as frame: {{0, 0}, {768, 1024}}

     UITouch* touch = [[event touchesForView:self] anyObject]; 
     location = [touch locationInView:self];
     NSLog(@"Location: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(location));

}


- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
     CGRect bounds = [self bounds]; 

     UITouch* touch = [[event touchesForView:self] anyObject]; 
     location = [touch locationInView:self];
     NSLog(@"Location: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(location));

}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

     CGRect bounds = [self bounds]; 

     UITouch* touch = [[event touchesForView:self] anyObject]; 
     location = [touch locationInView:self];
     NSLog(@"Location: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(location));

}
```

Comment: Are these touches happening in a view controller who's view is offset on the main window at all?

Comment: These touch methods are implemented in a subclass of UIView. This view was then added to a view controller. This view has x = 0, y = 0, width = 768 and height = 1024 (from Size Inspector).

Comment: My guess would be that your interface build is somehow messed up, like an incorrectly aligned view or similar. Try to create a completely new project and see if it works there.

Comment: The view's frame is {{0,0}, {768, 1024}}.

Comment: Try, when instantiating the view, to set the view's frame to the view controller's bounds: [view setFrame:self.view.bounds];

Comment: I tried [myView setFrame:self.view.bounds] and get {{0,0},{768,1004}} for [myView frame]. The height of my view was cut off by 20 pixels at the  bottom. However, the shift in the coordinate values doesn't change.

Comment: Can you post your entire UIView's .m code? And the instantiation of the View in the controller.

Comment: Are you using IB or Storyboards for your interfaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The -20 offset on the y values is fixed by setting "Status bar is initially hidden" to YES. The rest of the problem looks like it's a hardware issue because I got a different range for x and y values each time I run the program on the iPad. I didn't get this problem while running the program on the simulator. On the simulator, x values range from 1 to 767 and y values range from 1 to 1023, which are pretty correct.

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot comment yet, I have to post an answer. Have you tried setting the background color of the view to a different color so that you can see if its in the top left corner for sure?

Comment: Yes, I did try setting the background color of the view to a different color: self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor], and it's in the top left corner. This trace `CGRect thisFrame = [self frame];
 NSLog(@"THIS FRAME: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(thisFrame));` does give {{0,0},{768,1024}}

Comment: If I changed the y value from the Size Inspector to -20, the y values of the touch locations seem to be correct (range from 0 to 1024), but I don't understand why?? Still couldn't make the x values look right (the far left touch has x at 6).
 
My view controller has an image view (as background). The view that has the touch methods is added to the view controller on top of the imageview background.

Comment: Try using [self frame] instead of bounds and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I have for the view:

```
@implementation TouchesView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:0.6f blue:0.6f alpha:1.0f]];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint touch = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    NSLog(@"(%.1f, %.1f)", touch.x, touch.y);
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(touch));
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{}

@end
```

And this is the initialization and adding it to a view controller:

```
TouchesView *touchView = [[TouchesView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview:touchView];
```

This works fine for me.

Comment: Hi RileyE, thanks for your help! What are the ranges for your x and y values when trying this code? Did you get 0-768 and 0-1024?

Comment: Yup! I didn't have any problems with it. Are you by chance running an audio or network app in the background? That would definitely cause some interference with coordinates (if the app status bar is up - personal hotspot or radio bar). Also, have you hidden the status bar on your app?

Comment: Yes, I did hide the status bar, and it removed the -20 offset from y. However, I kept getting different ranges for x and y each time ((-6,761) and (0,1024); then (6,768) and (-6, 1017); and others...). I didn't have the problem when running on the simulator though. On simulator, I consistently get (1,767) and (1,1023). What do you think?

Comment: Hi RileyE, did you get the ranges 0-768 and 0-1024 on a simulator or an iPad? Did you actually get the values 0?

Comment: Its impossible to get the value zero since nobody has a finger or stylus thats about a pixel wide.